# How to prevent axios from posting before state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, blocking

I am having a problem that the post request is not sending the updated currentVideo state as setState seems to be nonblocking. How can i make axios wait for the state to be set?

```
const nextVideo = () => {
    if (videoList.indexOf(currentVideo) < videoList.length - 1) {
      setCurrentVideo(videoList[videoList.indexOf(currentVideo) + 1]);
      setLoading(true);
      axios
        .post(`${BACK_PORT}/videos/download`, currentVideo)
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data) {
            setLoading(false);
          } else {
            console.log("waiting...");
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert(error)
        });
    } else {
      alert("This is the last video");
    }
  };
```

Comment: Setting state is fully asynchronous, have you looked into using an [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) on the `currentVideo` state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable and store the currentvideo value in it. Then use that variable at both the places,i.e., for setting up the state and making the axios call.

```
const nextVideo = () => {
    if (videoList.indexOf(currentVideo) < videoList.length - 1) {
      let currentVideo = videoList[videoList.indexOf(currentVideo) + 1] //change here
      setCurrentVideo(currentVideo );
      setLoading(true);
      axios
        .post(`${BACK_PORT}/videos/download`, currentVideo)
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data) {
            setLoading(false);
          } else {
            console.log("waiting...");
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert(error)
        });
    } else {
      alert("This is the last video");
    }
};
```